# PSQL how to do math between JSONB fields?

Tags: jsonp, calculated-columns, psql

So I have table with "data" type JSONB column. I want do some calculations add/sub between values in the row. How I can do that?

```
   psql> select 2 + ("data"->'field') - ("data"->'anotherField') from js_data_table;
```

This one produces an syntax error [42601].

Comment: There's no such thing as a `jsonp` data type. Do you mean `jsonb`? Also, show the *full, exact error text*.

Comment: Yep, exactly. And I think I've found the way 

           select 2 + ("data"->'field')::NUMERIC

in that case no error